# The chance of 1 out of 2 are selected out of 6

Tags: combinations, education

The problem: You have 6 people, out of those people 2 are selected. This is 15 combinations.

But when trying to calculate what the chance of a specific person out of the 2 being selected out of the 6. As far as I understand it, it would be 1/6th (first choice) and 1/5th (the second choice), but is that right?

Comment: there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose 2 people out of 6, a specific person appears in the choosen two 5times. so the probability is $\frac{5}{15}$?

Comment: So what's the chance of one of the two people being $X$?

Comment: The question is not clear.  Say the people are $a_1,\cdots, a_6$.  What event exactly are you trying to compute the probability of?

Comment: If the question is "what is the probability that $a_1$ is chosen if we choose two people uniformly at random (without replacement) from the six?" then the answer is obviously $\frac 13$.